# Why do nearby thunderstorms move in different directions?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, wind, thunderstorm

The image below from the Australian [Bureau of Meteorology](http://www.bom.gov.au/) shows several thunderstorms in southeast Queensland today and the directions they are expected to move.

I'm surprised how different these directions are. I had imagined that

- the main influence on a storm's trajectory would be high level winds, and
- the high level winds would be relatively uniform in such an area, being unaffected by geographical features (hills, rivers).

But that doesn't seem to fit with this evidence.

What factors influence the direction of a storm's movement?

[image: Thunderstorms in south-east Queensland]

Comment: i am presuming there is involvement of friction and that plays a role in the storm movement especially in the planetary boundary layer.

Comment: https://earth.nullschool.net/ in no way answers your question, but looks really cool.

Comment: I would expect vertical convection to play important role

Comment: @Gabija Would you suggest that the type of ground cover and terrain would influence the convection and thereby the direction?

Comment: @John I think 2nd chapter in this paper (http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0477%281988%29069%3C0272%3ATPTF%3E2.0.CO%3B2) suggests that at least their origin depends on convection caused by topography.

Comment: So I wonder whether my mental model should be (a) thunderstorms in location X will almost always travel in direction Y, or (b) it's just too complex to predict heuristically, leave it to the models. Maybe there's something in between.